# Чем отличаются стрелочные функции из ECMAScript от лябда-выражений в Java?

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, лямбда-выражение

Мой основной язык - TypeScript, со стрелочными функциями, доступными с ECMAScript-2015, я работаю давно.
Лямбда-выражения в Java выглядят очень похожим образом. Это принципиально разные вещи, или просто разные названия?

Comment: Смысл тот же, синтаксис, естественно, разный

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, благодарю Вас за комментарий. А почему в ECMAScript не стали употреблять это название? Ни в одном уроке по JavaScript или TypeScript не слышал, чтобы так кто-то назвал стрелочную функцию.

Comment: @БоковГлеб, потому что лямбда-функции - это более широкое понятие и в javascript - это любая безымянная функция, не только стрелочная, и возможно, даже именованная функция